# htaccess rewrite rules on single page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to change:

```
domain/link to domain/index.php?q=link
```

and

```
domain/notice/20151212/title-with-a to domain/index.php?q=notice&date=20151212&title=Title-with-a
```

with this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^notice/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?q=notice&date=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

If i enter into `domain/link or domain/link2`, goes well but if i try to enter to `domain/notice/20151212/title-with-a`, I can't because it cant get CSS, image, JS files (tries to get `domain/notice/20151212/js/theme.js` when the file is in `domain/js/theme.js`) but i can enter without problems by the URL:

```
domain/index.php?q=notice&date=20151212&title=Title-with-a
```

What am I doing wrong?

I check this regex on http://htaccess.mwl.be/ and i think the htaccess file is right.

Thank you.

Comment: Simple solution : add a base tag to the head of your document , **<base href="/">**

Comment: thank you, i had tried to put RewriteBase on the .htacces but i ignored that

Answer (score 0):

try to do this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^notice/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?q=notice&date=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

and try to revert order like here

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^notice/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?q=notice&date=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

**EDIT**
add [L] at the end of second line and try my url, it works

http://lab.maurosala.it/notice/a/b/

if you don't want the / at the end of url use this

```
RewriteRule ^notice/([^/]+)/([^/]+) notice.php?q=notice&date=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: thanks but changing the order i get the same result and the first one i think (is not a valid rule) doesnt resolve my problem